# How can I to know If my server run mongodb 64 bits?

Tags: mongodb, version, database

I have a remote server in linode with ubuntu lucid 10.04 64 bits.

I have installed mongodb from mongodb repo:

If I write mongo in console I get:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.3
connecting to: test
>
```

I want to know if my database mongodb is 64 bits. I can not use 32 bits mongodb database. I need use 64 bits mongodb database.

**How or where can I check it?**

**If my database mongodb is not 64 bits, how can I install mongodb 64 bits in ubuntu lucid 10.04 64bits?**

Thank you!

Comment: Obviously, if you had installed from a repo then your system has installed the 64bit version by default. You can verify that by doing locate mongodb-10gen | grep deb.

Comment: Thank you I get `-bash: mongodb-10gen: command not found` if I run `user@user:~$ mongodb-10gen | grep deb`

Comment: locate mongodb-10gen | grep deb

Comment: thank you I get the same result  `-bash: locate: command not found`

Comment: apt-get update && apt-get install locate

Comment: now after install locate If I write `user@user:~$ locate mongodb-10gen | grep deb` I get nothing in console
`user@user:~$`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9275/discussion-between-hymloth-and-hyperrjas)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the buildInfo command to find out what build your server is. Look for the value fo the bits field to see if you are using a 64-bit build.

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.runCommand("buildInfo")
{
"version" : "2.0.0",
"gitVersion" : "695c67dff0ffc361b8568a13366f027caa406222",
"sysInfo" : "Darwin erh2.10gen.cc 9.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 9.6.0: Mon Nov 24 17:37:00 PST 2008; root:xnu-1228.9.59~1/RELEASE_I386 i386 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_40",
"versionArray" : [
    2,
    0,
    0,
    0
],
"bits" : 64,
"debug" : false,
"maxBsonObjectSize" : 16777216,
"ok" : 1
}
>
```

Comment: Thank you RobertStam, it does works fine for me :D. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

As of v2.4.6, my mongo client displays the following as soon as it connects to `mongod`, if the server is 32-bit. I don't even need to run a command.

```
** NOTE: This is a 32 bit MongoDB binary.
**       32 bit builds are limited to less than 2GB of data (or less with --journal).
**       Note that journaling defaults to off for 32 bit and is currently off.
**       See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/32bit
```